# Adding a field in Jackson in derived class again, which has been ignored in base class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I encountered a strange phenomenon in Jackson:
I added a mixin for a base class (`AbstractPersistentObject`), containing just a `@JsonIgnore` for a field (id), as I wanted to suppress it in all derived classes. This worked well.

Now I want to export this field for exactly one derived class (`Product`).

Therefore I configured a mixin for this class like this:

```
@JsonAppend(
                attrs = {
                    @JsonAppend.Attr(value="id", include=Include.ALWAYS)
                }
            )
...
```

This worked in so far as this field is now exported for this entity, but its value is always given as `null`, where the value of this field in the object is definitely not null. How come? And what can I do to make this field with its correct value reappear in the generated JSON?

I also tried to export this field with another name, specifying `propName="productId"` in `@JsonAppend`, but this newly named field also always has the value `null`.

Also `@JsonProperty("productId") public abstract String getId();` in the said mixin did not work; the field did not appear again.

Maybe it is not possible to treat properties of a base class properly in a derived class?

I definitely do not want to exclude this field in every derived class except the one, as there are quite a lot of them; and there might come more, which would have to be treated alike (which I will forget then ;o).

I use jackson 2.6.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long and frustrating investigations I finally found a working solution.
I needed to write a subclass of VirtualBeanPropertyWriter, which returns the value of the id field of the object:

```java
public class VirtualBeanProductIdPropertyWriter extends VirtualBeanPropertyWriter {

    public VirtualBeanProductIdPropertyWriter() {
    }

    public VirtualBeanProductIdPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyDefinition propDef, Annotations contextAnnotations, JavaType declaredType)
    {
        super(propDef, contextAnnotations, declaredType);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object value(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
        if(bean instanceof AbstractPersistentObject) {
            return ((AbstractPersistentObject) bean).getId();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public VirtualBeanPropertyWriter withConfig(MapperConfig<?> config, AnnotatedClass declaringClass, BeanPropertyDefinition propDef, JavaType type) {
        return new VirtualBeanProductIdPropertyWriter(propDef, null, type);
    }
}
```

and configure it in the mixin like this:

```java
@JsonAppend(prepend=true, 
                props = {
                    @JsonAppend.Prop(name="productId", value=VirtualBeanProductIdPropertyWriter.class, include=Include.ALWAYS, required=true)
                }
            )
...
```

It really looks like the variant with `attrs` cannot reference inherited attributes.